# Login button not showing in android app in meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am trying to develop android app of todo in meteor 1.3. When I do so, login button is not showing in android app. However its working perfectly on the browser as well as in emulator.

```
accounts-ui version: 1.1.9
```

Any clue/solution for this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is problem with your phone resolution.Try to use other mobile which resolution is supported